# Why is this lifecycle hook code working twice?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

There is such a code:

```
<template>

   <div class="wrapper">
   </div>

</template>

<script>

import axios from 'axios';

export default{

  created () {
    console.log('222');
    this.getTrackerIdData();
    this.getTrackerData();
  },

  methods: {

    getTrackerIdData () {
        return axios.get("https://seo-gmbh.eu/couriertracker/json/couriertracker_api.php?action=tracking_new.create" , {
         })
        .then(response => {
          this.$store.commit('tracker/setTrackingKeyId', response.data.data.tracking_new_key_id);
          this.$store.commit('tracker/setQrCodeUrl', response.data.data.filename_qr_code_tracking_new);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
    },

    getTrackerData () {

        setInterval(()=>myTimer(this), 60000);

        function myTimer(th) {
             return axios.get("https://seo-gmbh.eu/couriertracker/json/couriertracker_api.php?action=get_tracking_data&key_id=" + th.$store.state.tracker.trackingKeyId , {
             })
            .then(response => {
              th.$store.commit('tracker/setTrackingServerData', response.data.data.tracking_data);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
              console.log(error);
            });
        }

},

  }
}
</script>
```

When starting such a solution in the project, the server-side developer informed me that at least the request method `getTrackerIdData ()` on its side works twice! 
Having placed the code (`console.log ('222');`) in the hook of the `created` lifecycle (where the method calls), I found that it is displayed twice in the firebug:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Question: 
Why is this happening and what approach is right in this case from the point of view of the implementation of receiving data from the server?

P.S. If everything is called in the `mounted` hook, then the code works, including on the server side, only 1 time.

Comment: It looks like one is coming from the SSR and the other from the client-side rendering. The `mounted` hook is not called during SSR.

Comment: I have another project without any middleware at all and there at is the same problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is important to know that in any Vue instance lifecycle, only beforeCreate and created hooks are called both from client-side and server-side. All other hooks are called only from the client-side.

so thats why created hook called 2 times and executing the **console.log ('222');** twice

for reference you can read from [here](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins)

Comment: I don't exactly understand - in which case needs code call twice?
(from point of view real practical tasks.)
Why is it need?
What it is cases?

Comment: for spa mode only client site active, in that case beforeCreate and created hooks are called only once. but for universal mode there is server and client part in that case beforeCreate and created hooks are called 2 times

Comment: but there is a option to call only once, do you want that also?

Comment: I just curious - why does it need to call some code twice?
If this possible exists (calling this code once) - of course it is interesting - how it works?