# NuxtJS Page is created twice

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I am currently facing an Issue in **NuxtJS** where a **method is called twice** and a request is therefore sent twice.

This happens in a **page** and the method which is called twice is **created**().

I open the page with a **parameter** like:

```
http://localhost:3000/mypage?token=123123123
```

And in the created() Method of the page I call a store dispatch.

```js
created() {
  if (this.token === undefined || this.token === null) {
    this.$router.push('/login')
  } else {
    console.log('called created() and sent dispatch')
    this.$store.dispatch('thirdPartyLogin', {
      token: this.token
    })
  }
},
```

The token is parsed via the data property:

```js
data() {
  return {
    token: this.$nuxt.$route.query.token
  }
},
```

The problem with this is that it is a One Time Token, which means that it is invalid after one use. So after the second call no more success of the request can take place.

**Why is the page created twice or created() called twice?**

[image: Dev-tools screenshot]

Comment: see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60199338/why-is-this-lifecycle-hook-code-working-twice/60199674#60199674

Answer (score 10, accepted):

created() and beforeCreate() are two lifehooks which are called on the server side and client side both. (you will see one console log in your terminal too, because server is firing i)

If you want to do this once you can :

a) use mounted() hook

b) if action needs to be done earlier than mounted u have to use if statement inside created method `process.client`. This if statement will check if you are on the client(browser side) if so, do the action

```
created(){
  if(process.client){
    //...your action here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how it works:

Nuxt.js runs `created()` once on the server side then on the client side.

The `Nuxt SSR` shows the `console.log` message of your server and the second `console.log` is the message on the client side.

You have 2 Options:

Run this on the serverside:

Wrap it in:

```
   if(process.server){
   }
```

Or run it once on the client side:

```
   if(!process.server){
   }
```